# Multiple RabbitMQ or other backend servers in Node configs

Tags: javascript, node.js, rabbitmq

I am in DevOps and our developers insist that the software they wrote in Node.js is only able to point to a singular back end server, be it a database, web server or a RabbitMQ server due to shortcomings in Node.js. This sounds completely crazy to me. How is that possible?

Consider this in a `local.js` file

```
    rabbitmq:{
        host: "rabbit01.stage",
        port: 5672,
        username : "user",
        password : "pass",
        exchangeName: "exchange_blah",
        queueName: "queue_blah",
        name : "rabbit",
        max : 10
    }
```

Changing the config to

```
            host: ["rabbit01.stage", "rabbit02.stage" ],
```

breaks the application and it attempts to find rabbit server on `localhost:5672`

My Google-fu is failing me, because I am not sure how to properly formulate this question into a searchable phrase.

Am I missing something here? Or our developers should RTFM?

Comment: Are they saying that the setting needs to be hardcoded? Oh, I  just realized what's going on. The change you're making to the json in your example would break their code. They aren't expecting an array, just a single field. So yes, they're right.

Comment: @PaulSasik: I am not sure I understand the question. Is there a dynamic way to do that? They are saying they can specify 1 rabbit server and 1 rabbit server only, and they seem to have no idea how to specify more than 1.... fault tolerance be damned....

Comment: You're looking at a design issue. They probably never considered multiple servers. Without seeing the code I can only speculate. If you want the servers to behave differently you will have to handle this differently. This is more of a personal/prj mgmt issue than a logical onw.

Comment: @PaulSasik: well, they have to, because I am not putting that software in production unless they implement some kind of fault tolerance. Do they need to make changes to their code to expect the host value to be an array? I've lost faith in their skills, so I have to tell them exactly what needs to be done.

Comment: Ah, you're expecting fail over functionality. That's not exactly trivial to implement. Was it an expected feature? Btw, you can try and handle this via configuration on your end. I haven't done this myself but I  know there are ways to have single IP backed up by several servers where a monitoring mechanism switches which server handles the IP if failure is detected. Good luck either way.

Comment: @PaulSasik: ok. I can easily implement load balancing/fault tolerance on my end either with haproxy or IP failover. I'm just really stick of having to spend my time to fix shortcomings in software that out incompetent developers write.

Comment: I understand where you're coming from but from the developers' view this is not automatic. Most software is not designed for HA because it is expensive to create and maintain that kind of feature. Another way to look at this is from the financial angle. I.e. Is there a business need for HA or is it OK if a server goes down for a few hours every once in a while? Is the software mission critical and requires 99.999% vs. 99% uptime. (Each one of those nines beyond the decimal point could be a million dollars in development costs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you're looking for (and you clearly know this) is clustering. You can point your devs to this article: https://www.rabbitmq.com/clustering.html

However, there is a key paragraph down below where it discusses connecting to a clustered configuration:

> Generally, it's not advisable to bake in node hostnames or IP addresses into client applications: this introduces inflexibility and will require client applications to be edited, recompiled and redeployed should the configuration of the cluster change or the number of nodes in the cluster change. Instead, we recommend a more abstracted approach: this could be a dynamic DNS service which has a very short TTL configuration, or a plain TCP load balancer, or some sort of mobile IP achieved with pacemaker or similar technologies. In general, this aspect of managing the connection to nodes within a cluster is beyond the scope of RabbitMQ itself, and we recommend the use of other technologies designed specifically to solve these problems.

The gist of this says that the developers should only attempt to maintain a connection to a single DNS entry and that some sort of DNS or IP based load balancing should be used to prevent the code from having to know about multiple connections.

Some of the benefits are listed in the same article, and most of them come down to the complexity that handling this in code would add to the code. Generally, load balancers are better at doing this because they are purpose built and understand the intricate nature of doing this.

If a developer were required to handle this in code, they would have to write a software version of a load balancer or dynamic DNS lookup. This would be prone to errors and miscalculations far more frequently than using a network device to handle the needs.

So... while you are correct that your node.js developers *can* do what you want... they are on the right track in saying that they shouldn't *have* to do it because it would be a bad idea to do this in code compared to doing it in hardware / network layer.